# JSDoc required parameter with default value

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I found the [following](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#optional-parameters-and-default-values) for document an optional parameter in JSDoc.:

```
/**
 * @param {string} [somebody=John Doe] - Somebody's name.
 */
function sayHello(somebody) {
    if (!somebody) {
        somebody = 'John Doe';
    }
    alert('Hello ' + somebody);
}
```

and this for document parameters object properties.

```
/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employee.name - The name of the employee.
 * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function(employee) {
    // ...
};
```

Now I want document a required object parameter in JSDoc. Something like this.:

```
/**
 * Assign the project to an employee.
 * @param {Object} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 * @param {string} employee.name=John Doe - The name of the employee.
 * @param {string} employee.department - The employee's department.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function(employee) {
    // ...
};
```

How can I do that?

Maybe the solution `@param {string} employee.name=John Doe - The name of the employee.` is already the correct one?

Comment: Can you specify a little bit more what your goal is? I personally can't understand your question.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  Per "Parameters with properties" in https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html:

> If a parameter is expected to have a specific property, you can document that property by providing an additional @param tag.

However, if you're going to re-use those properties in other functions you might want to instead define an `Employee` type:

```
/**
 * The employee who is responsible for the project
 * @typedef {Object} Employee
 * @property {string} name - The name of the employee
 * etc.
 */

/*
 * @param {Employee} employee - The employee who is responsible for the project.
 */
Project.prototype.assign = function(employee) {
```

https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html